# how many fewer grames of caffeine is she consuming each week?

Tags: education

how many fewer grames of caffeine is she consuming each week?[image]

I try with the following

2*97*7 + 5 * 6 *7 = 1358 +210 = 1568 mg convert to gram = 1.568

but not correct , please help how calculate ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the difference, not the sum.